# Simplifying $A'B'C'D+A'B'CD+A'BC'D'+A'BC'D+A'BCD'+AB'C'D'+AB'C'D+ABC'D'+ABCD'+ABCD$ to $A'B'D+A'C'D+AB'C'+ABC+BD'$ (and another)

Tags: boolean-algebra

I have been at this for hours using boolean algebra (not K-maps) and always end up so close but cannot reach the solutions.

This is one expression:
$$A'B'C'D + A'B'CD + A'BC'D' + A'BC'D + A'BCD' + AB'C'D' \\+ AB'C'D + ABC'D' + ABCD' + ABCD \tag{1a}$$
and its simplification is
$$A'B'D + A'C'D + AB'C' + ABC + BD' \tag{1b}$$

This is the second:
$$A'B'C'D' + A'B'C'D + A'BC'D + A'BCD + AB'C'D' + AB'C'D \\
+ AB'CD' + ABC'D' + ABC'D + ABCD \tag{2a}$$
and this is the simplification:
$$BD + AC’ + B’C’ \tag{2b}$$

Can these be done using boolean algebra

---

Edit
This is one of my attempts at the second expression:

[image]

Comment: Are you familiar with how distribution works in boolean algebra?

Comment: Yes I've used distribution, and XY + XY' = X, and identity and idempotence... I don't seem to reach the answers. I'm always just one variable off...

Comment: Can you include your attempts?

Comment: Why not solving it first with K-diagrams, then, inspired by them, obtain the purely-boolean way ?

Comment: The solutions that I need to get to are already obtained by K-diagrams. I need to specifically get to these answers using algebra now...

Comment: @Stephen Donovan I added one of my attempts at the second expression where I got one term more than the expected simplified result.

Comment: You're nearly there on the second expression, I believe we can eliminate the extra term by factoring and redistributing the $AC' + AB'D',$ and then noting that we can get an extra $AC'D$ term from terms 5 and 8

Answer (score 1):

This is a classic application of K-V map (Karnaugh Map). Just implemented the algorithm in `python` for 4 variables. The function accepts the Boolean function in SOP (sum of products) form and the names of the variables and returns a simplified reduced representation. Basically you need to create rectangular groups containing total terms in power of two like 8, 4, 2 and try to cover as many elements as you can in one group (we need to cover all the ones).

For example, the function

$
\begin{array}
f(A,B,C,D) = & A′B′C′D+A′B′CD+A′BC′D′+A′BC′D+A′BCD′+AB′C′D′+ \\
           &  AB′C′D+ABC′D′+ABCD′+ABCD
\end{array}
$

can be represented as

$f(A,B,C,D)=\sum(1,3,4,5,6,8,9,12,14,15)$.

As can be seen from the output of the next code snippet, the program outputs the simplified form $B\bar{D} + \bar{A}B\bar{C} + A\bar{B}\bar{C} + ABC +  \bar{A}\bar{B}D$, where negation of a boolean variable $A$ is represented $\bar{A}$ and equivalently as $¬A$ in the code.

```
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import permutations, product
    
def kv_map(sop, vars):
    
    sop = set(sop)
    not_covered = sop.copy()
    sop_covered = set([])
    
    mts = [] # minterms
    
    # check for minterms with 1 variable
    all_3 = [''.join(x) for x in product('01', repeat=3)]
    for i in range(4):
        for v_i in [0,1]:
                if len(not_covered) == 0: continue
                mt = ('' if v_i else '¬') + vars[i]
                s = [x[:i]+str(v_i)+x[i:] for x in all_3]
                sop1 = set(map(lambda x: int(x,2), s))
                if len(sop1 & sop) == 8 and len(sop_covered & sop1) < 8: # if not already covered
                    mts.append(mt)
                    sop_covered |= sop1
                    not_covered = not_covered - sop1
        if len(not_covered) == 0:
           return mts
    
    # check for minterms with 2 variables
    all_2 = [''.join(x) for x in product('01', repeat=2)]
    for i in range(4):
        for j in range(i+1, 4):
            for v_i in [0,1]:
                for v_j in [0,1]:
                    if len(not_covered) == 0: continue
                    mt = ('' if v_i else '¬') + vars[i] + ('' if v_j else '¬') + vars[j]
                    s = [x[:i]+str(v_i)+x[i:] for x in all_2]
                    s = [x[:j]+str(v_j)+x[j:] for x in s]
                    sop1 = set(map(lambda x: int(x,2), s))
                    if len(sop1 & sop) == 4 and len(sop_covered & sop1) < 4: # if not already covered
                        mts.append(mt)
                        sop_covered |= sop1
                        not_covered = not_covered - sop1
    if len(not_covered) == 0:
        return mts

    # check for minterms with 3 variables similarly (code omitted)
    # ... ... ...
    
    return mts
    
kv_map([1,3,4,5,6,8,9,12,14,15], ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
mts
# ['B¬D', '¬AB¬C', 'A¬B¬C', 'ABC', '¬A¬BD']
```

The following animation shows how the above code (greedily) simplifies the Boolean function given in SOP form (the basic goal is to cover all the $1$s with minimum number of power-2 blocks).

[image]

Since the algorithm is greedy it may get stuck to some local minimum, that we need to be careful about (can be improved!).

Comment: +1 very interesting ! A detail on the second line: some of product $\to$ sums of products.